# list of default @types provided by hibernate out of the box

Tags: hibernate

I'm using this annotation on a class, to map my ID to uuid:

```
@Type(type="pg-uuid")
```

I would like to know what others default types are available, but I didn't found a list anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the types are under `org.hibernate.type` and for Hibernate 5.1 the list is [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/package-summary.html).

If you want to get the name of a particular type that you would use in the `@Type` annotation in your entity, then you would need to look at the source of particular type definition class and it will be there in the `getName` method.